# Org-mode nested properties?

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

[Org manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Properties-and-Columns.html#Properties-and-Columns) says *"A property is a key-value pair associated with an entry"*. A proper [key-value data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) can store anything in a value, including another associative array. But properties seemingly can't.

- **Can i emulate nested properties?**
- If i can't, **how should it be elegantly implemented in theory?**

The nested properties could enable many possibilities for org-mode through the heavy use of [Property API](http://orgmode.org/manual/Property-API.html#Property-API) for countless features. Examples that spring up in mind include: a key-value database, a graph database, adding complex semantic metadata to entries, semantic web apps, even text quests.

A similar idea of [ID markers](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/11896/) ([all posts of the thread](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/cgi-bin/namazu.cgi?query=[Orgmode]+Feature+request%3A+IDs+on+anything+&submit=Search!&idxname=emacs-orgmode&max=20&result=normal&sort=score)) was discussed on org-mode mailing list in 2009. The idea of ID markers is tangentially related to my another desire to generalize org-mode property syntax from [Org-mode: using special properties in the drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13228158/596361). Unfortunately ID markers introduce even more new syntax, and i want to enable the nested data storing incrementally, within current org-mode abilities.

[Babel](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/index.html) could be a solution, but it requires using programming languages and possibly limits the flexibility. It would be better to use property API only.

Comment: Do you really need properties for that ? If you want to go the database way, why don't you use named tables, to be called by org-babel code blocks ?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you have in mind:

```
** subheading
   :PROPERTIES:
   :my-prop:  (:property-1 red :property-2 (nested-prop . 5))
   :END:`


#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
    (defun get-my-prop-value (property)
       (interactive)
       (plist-get
       (read (org-entry-get (point) "my-prop"))
       property))
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: get-my-prop-value



#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
    (get-my-prop-value :property-2)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: (nested-prop . 5)
```