# Org-mode: using special properties in the drawer

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

[Org manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Special-properties.html#Special-properties) says special properties *"should not be used as keys in the properties drawer"*. However i want to use org-mode on a more high level and i want to put all special properties in the `:PROPERTIES:` drawer.

This can be used for many reasons, for example, i can write an external parser, that can understand org-mode files, that consist of only entries with properties, without needing to know about TODO, tags, priorities and their syntax in the headline. This should change the behavior of all org-mode commands, that usually obey the ad hoc org-mode syntax. For example, `org-todo` would change a `TODO` property in the drawer, instead of changing the headline, and so on.

In other words, **I want to generalize org-mode syntax a bit. How can i do that in theory and practice? What should i need to know and do?**

Answer (score 1):

The only way (both theoretically and practically) is to rewrite org-mode to enable that.  The special properties (closed, scheduled etc) are assumed by existing code to be outside drawers, immediately below the header, todo items must be immediately after the stars and :tags: on the first line.
Tags should be easiest to reroute to a drawer as some functionality does this already. Closed, scheduled and deadline are well defined and movable. Placing todo status in drawers may be a big job.